# PHP - sending empty value and getting Undefined index in the console

Tags: php

I"m sending to a php code a json string named- student

```
$scope.student = {name: "Joe", grades: "85", info: ""};
```

Now the php code is simple -

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    //read the json file contents
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("php://input");

    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    $studentname = $data['studentname'];
    $stuedentgrades = $data['stuedentgrades'];
    $studentinfo = $data['studentinfo'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO students (name, grades, info)
VALUES ('$studentname', '$stuedentgrades', '$studentinfo')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The thing is that sometimes the "info" can be empty and i would like to pass it empty to the server - but I'm getting -

```
 Undefined index: info
```

Now i tried to add  to the code the isset -

```
  `if(isset($_POST('info'))){

     $info= $data['info'];
}else{
    echo "NOOOOOOOOOO";
}   ` 


$studentname = $data['studentname'];
    $stuedentgrades = $data['stuedentgrades'];
    $studentinfo = $data['studentinfo'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO students (name, grades, info)
VALUES ('$studentname', '$stuedentgrades', '$studentinfo')";
```

but it didn't seems to do the work.

So what am I doing wrong?
How can I pass empty value into the table?

As you can see I'm novice when it comes to PHP so any help would be nice

Comment: question is ambiguous because of these:- `$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);$studentname = $data['studentname']; ... others`  and then  `isset($_POST('info')` you are telling that you passed object. but it seems that you passed json string . Also indexes mismatched in input date shown to us and code that you shown

Comment: you are right I am passing Json string my bad

Comment: Use it `$info = (!empty($data['info']))? $data['info']:'Noooooo';`

Comment: `The thing is that sometimes the "info" can be empty ` ? what do you mean here. that index is there but value is empty or you want to say that sometime index `info` is missing?

Comment: I simply want to pass whatever "info" is, so lets say it is empty i want to pass the empty to the table cell that's all - but i get this undefined index error. And yes the index is there but the value is empty

Comment: `[name: "Joe", grades: "85", info: ""];` is invalid Javascript. `[]` is for arrays, but `name: value` pairs go into objects. It should be `$scope.student = {name: "Joe", grades: "85", info: ""};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hope it will help you (please read comments (`//...`) carefully and check changes):-***

```
$scope.student = [name: "Joe", grades: "85", info: ""]; // `.` from variable name eed to be removed in any manner
```

Now i assume it's:-

```
$scope = [name: "Joe", grades: "85", info: ""];
```

Now the php code is simple -

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    //read the json file contents
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("php://input");

    //convert json object to php associative array
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
     // here i assume that $data is exactly equals what you shown above that means $data = [name: "Joe", grades: "85", info: ""];

    //Now  change here:-

    $studentname = (!empty($data['name']))? $data['name'] : ""; //check change here
    $stuedentgrades = (!empty($data['grades']))? $data['grades'] : "";
    $studentinfo = (!empty($data['info']))? $data['info'] : "Nooooo";

$sql = "INSERT INTO students (name, grades, info)
VALUES ('$studentname', '$stuedentgrades', '$studentinfo')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST('info')` is not the correct way to access an array from post

try

```
if(isset($_POST['info'])){
     $info= $_POST['info'];
}else{
    echo "NOOOOOOOOOO";
}
```

or

```
if(isset($data['student']['info'])){
     $info= $data['student']['info'];
}else{
    echo "NOOOOOOOOOO";
}
```